# How to execute service functions using keys from an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array which contains information from separate services, some of which may or may not be present and are interchangeable.

e.g.    `$scope.services = [{facebook: data}, {twitter: data}, {instagram: data}];`

I then have to get data from the given services via methods named with the same conventions e.g `facebookTimeline.get();` or `instagramTimeline.get();`

How can I make it so that I can execute these functions based on the key values that are present inside the `$scope.services` array? I've considered `for (key in $scope.services)` although not sure how to execute the functions with the keys as a string. I'm unable to modify how the objects are formatted and stored in `$scope.services`.

**EDIT**: code example

```
angular.module('app').controller('TimelineController', ['$scope', 'instagramTimeline','facebookTimeline', 'twitterTimeline', function($scope, instagramTimeline, facebookTimeline, twitterTimeline){

    $scope.services = {facebook: tokenString, instagram: tokenString, twitter: tokenString};

    for(var key in $scope.services){
        //how would i access <key>Timeline service?
        ('key' + 'Timeline').get()
    }


}])

//example factory

.factory('instagramTimeline', [function(){
   var api = {};
   api.data = [1,2,3,4];
   api.get = function(){
       return data;
   }
}]);
```

Comment: for (key in $scope.services) { $scope.services[key].get(); } ???

Comment: $scope.services[key] would just be the value of `data` which is just an object, and not the angular service i'm trying to use (so it would have no get() method)

Comment: and what's your angular service? edit your question, put your code and what you've tried already, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a 4th factory called something like 'socialTimeline' that returns the following API (you need to inject this new factory service with facebookTimeline, twitterTimeline and instagramTimeline) :

```
{
     facebookTimelineService: facebookTimeline, // this is your existing factory
     twitterTimelineService: twitterTimeline, 
     instagramTimelineService: instagramTimeline 
}
```

Then call each by doing

```
socialTimeline[key + 'TimelineService' ].get()
```

PD: you can avoid the new factory and just create the object if you like. You just need some key-value pairing that has your other factories in order to get the one you want.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone else comes across this same problem, I've solved it using another service

```
.factory('apiLayer', ['instagramTimeline', 'facebookTimeline', 'twitterTimeline', function(instagramTimeline, facebookTimeline, twitterTimeline){

    var factory = {};

    factory.instagramTimeline = function(){ return instagramTimeline; }
    factory.facebookTimeline = function(){ return facebookTimeline; };
    factory.twitterTimeline = function(){ return twitterTimeline; };

    return factory;
}]);
```

and accessed it in the controller using

```
for(var key in $scope.services){
    apiLayer[key+'Timeline']().get();
}
```